# Hittisme: étymologie

Tags: étymologie, argot

Le hittisme désigne le fait de s'adosser à un mur par désœuvrement.

Exemples trouvés sur des forums:

> Vous les avez sans doute remarqués en Algérie, certains jeunes, plombés par le chômage et le « dégoûtage », finissent par banaliser le hittisme au point d'en faire presque un métier : le hittiste...
>
> [...] se débarrasser de l'idéologie petite bourgeoise, de cet immobilisme dans la tête, ce hittisme mental

Quel est l'étymologie de ce mot ?

Où et quand est-il apparu en premier ?

Answer (score 4):

Selon *[Le français en Algérie : Lexique et dynamique des langues](https://books.google.com/books?id=28CA67Tr4X0C&lpg=PA353&ots=STMGyO38xV&dq=hittisme&pg=PA353#v=onepage&q=hittisme&f=false)*, « hittisme » est un néologisme construit à partir de l'arabe « *hitt* », qui signifie « mur ».

Ce terme est apparu, fort probablement en Algérie, dans les années 1990, selon ce même livre.

Comment: J'ai appris quelque chose là! Je n'avais jamais entendu ce mot avant. Merci!